# LINQ Where Clause Behavior

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, search

I’m attempting to write a search routine and part of it includes the following code:

```
string searchValue = Server.HtmlEncode(RadSearchBox.Text.ToLower());

var injurySearchList = (from i in injuryObj
                        where i.IsDeleted == false &&
                        (
                            i.ResultOther == true ? "ResultOther".ToLower().Contains(searchValue) : i.IncidentID.ToString().Contains(searchValue)
                            || i.BodyPartHead == true ? "BodyPartHead".ToLower().Contains(searchValue) : i.IncidentID.ToString().Contains(searchValue)
                        )
                        select i.IncidentID).ToList();
```

Since I’m unable to search the bit values for a string, I use the ternary operator to evaluate if it’s true.  If so, I [manually] convert the field name to a string and see if that contains the search string.  If the bit value is false, I’d prefer to exclude that line from the WHERE clause but was unable to come up with any clever ideas, so I used the conversion of the IncidentID field to a string with a Contains() method as a filler.

Using the following dataset as an example:

```
+------------+-------------+--------------+-----------+
| IncidentID | ResultOther | BodyPartHead | IsDeleted |
+------------+-------------+--------------+-----------+
|          1 |           0 |            1 |         0 |
|          2 |           1 |            1 |         0 |
|          3 |           0 |            1 |         0 |
+------------+-------------+--------------+-----------+
```

The issue is when searchValue equals “body”, it’s only returning IncidentID 1 and 3, but 2 should be in there as well.  Inversely, if searchValue equals “result”, it only returns IncidentID 2, as intended.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an order-of-operations issue.  `OR` (`||`) is evaluated *before* the conditional ternary operator.  You need to surround the two `OR` operations with parentheses:

```
where i.IsDeleted == false &&
(
    (i.ResultOther == true ? "ResultOther".ToLower().Contains(searchValue) : i.IncidentID.ToString().Contains(searchValue))
    || (i.BodyPartHead == true ? "BodyPartHead".ToLower().Contains(searchValue) : i.IncidentID.ToString().Contains(searchValue))
)
```

You original code is equivalent to:

```
where i.IsDeleted == false &&
(
    i.ResultOther == true 
        ? "ResultOther".ToLower().Contains(searchValue) 
        : (i.IncidentID.ToString().Contains(searchValue)) || (i.BodyPartHead == true)
              ? "BodyPartHead".ToLower().Contains(searchValue) 
              : i.IncidentID.ToString().Contains(searchValue))
)
```

(you can also get rid of `== true` and use `!` instead of `== false`, but those don't change the results and are just cosmetic changes)

Comment: You're welcome.  BTW the answer you accepted wasn't first (I don't care which you accept just making sure you use the right criteria).

Comment: I was going off of what used to say "answered ## minutes ago" above each name.  Where can I find the date/time stamp?

Comment: Hover over the label after "answered".  Not a big deal (and I'm really not trying to get you to change your accepted answer) - just pointing it out.

Comment: I strive for accuracy and my intent was/is to award it to the first/correct solution, so it's been reapplied as intended.  Thanks for the solution and education, D!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need parantesis around the inner `? :` statements, like this:

```
var injurySearchList = (from i in injuryObj
                        where i.IsDeleted == false &&
                        (
                            (i.ResultOther == true
                                 ? "ResultOther".ToLower().Contains(searchValue)
                                 : i.IncidentID.ToString().Contains(searchValue))
                         || (i.BodyPartHead == true
                                 ? "BodyPartHead".ToLower().Contains(searchValue)
                                 : i.IncidentID.ToString().Contains(searchValue))
                            )
                        select i.IncidentID).ToList();
```

From how you describe what you actually want to accomplish, I think the following simplification gives you the same results:

```
var injurySearchList2 = (from i in injuryObj
                         where !i.IsDeleted 
                         && (
                             (i.ResultOther && "resultother".Contains(searchValue))
                          || (i.BodyPartHead  && "bodyparthead".Contains(searchValue))
                         )
                         select i.IncidentID).ToList();
```

Comment: Right answer as well and thank you for the simplification, that works even better.  I would throw an up-vote to this but don't have the rep quite yet.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put parentheses around the two conditions.  The second one is getting wrapped up into the first, like this:

```
where i.IsDeleted == false &&
(
    i.ResultOther == true ? "ResultOther".ToLower().Contains(searchValue) : (i.IncidentID.ToString().Contains(searchValue) || i.BodyPartHead == true ?  "BodyPartHead".ToLower().Contains(searchValue) : i.IncidentID.ToString().Contains(searchValue))
)
```

Should be:

```
where i.IsDeleted == false &&
(
    (i.ResultOther == true ? "ResultOther".ToLower().Contains(searchValue) : i.IncidentID.ToString().Contains(searchValue))
    || (i.BodyPartHead == true ?  "BodyPartHead".ToLower().Contains(searchValue) : i.IncidentID.ToString().Contains(searchValue))
)
```

Comment: That was it.  The other answers worked great, but you were first.  Thanks!